# Laravel getQueryString() without &amp;

Tags: laravel-blade

I'm trying to output a variable containing part of a URL into Javascript on my page. When I do this, it changes any `&` into `&amp;`, which breaks the URL.

I've tried using `str_replace`, `html_entity_decode`, `htmlspecialchars_decode` but the result was always same `&amp;` instead of `&`.

How i can get it with `&` instead of `&amp;` ?

This is my controller:

```
//here we catch the query
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $input   = $request->getQueryString();

        return view('lots.browse')->withInput($input);
    }

// here we filter the ajax request
public function indexData(LotFilters $filters)
    {
       $lots  = Lot::filter($filters);

        return Datatables::eloquent($lots)->make(true);
    }
```

This is my view:

```
<!-- Datatables -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#table').DataTable({
                searching: false,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{{  url("/data") . "?" .  html_entity_decode($input) }}',
                columns: [
                    { data: 'date', name: 'date' },
                    { data: 'bid', name: 'bid' },
                    { data: 'auction_name', name: 'auction_name' },
                    { data: 'pics_urls', name: 'pics_urls' },
                    { data: 'company', name: 'company' },
                    { data: 'model_name_en', name: 'model_name_en' },
                    { data: 'model_type_en', name: 'model_type_en' },
                    { data: 'grade_en', name: 'grade_en' },
                    { data: 'mileage_en', name: 'mileage_en' },
                    { data: 'model_year_en', name: 'model_year_en' },
                    { data: 'color_en', name: 'color_en' },
                    { data: 'displacement', name: 'displacement' },
                    { data: 'transmission_en', name: 'transmission_en' },
                    { data: 'scores_en', name: 'scores_en' },
                    { data: 'start_price_en', name: 'start_price_en' },
                    { data: 'result_en', name: 'result_en' }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using a blade template, `{{ $variable }}` will properly encode any characters that should not be placed directly in HTML. Since you're placing this variable in Javascript, you don't want this to happen.

The simplest solution is to disable HTML-encoding: `{{!! $variable !!}}`.

But this is not the full solution. You need to ensure that the variable isn't blindly output, since if it contains a single quote, it will break your Javascript.

The full solution is to escape the string for single quotes:

```
{{!! addcslashes($input, "'") !!}}
```

Comment: This is good, thanks. I think there is only one `{` needed like `{!! addcslashes($input, "'") !!}`

Answer (score 0):

try using rawurldecode it should fixe it.

Comment: unfortunately result is this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data?make[]=TOYOTA&amp;model[]=VITZ`

Comment: the &amp;  is still there instead of &, how is this possible. It just blows my mind !

Comment: did you try without using any decoder ? just {{ url("/data")."?".$input }} ?

Comment: Ha... Ya i replace decoder with rawurldecode($input)

Comment: ha .. no i mean just try it like this {{ url("/data")."?".$input }} because this is very weird it should work just fine without using any decoder.

Comment: Ya i tried and it returns same: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/data?make%5B%5D=TOYOTA&amp;model%5B%5D=VITZ`

Answer (score 0):

try using
`{!! url('?param1=test&param2=test2&param3=kiswahili') !!}`

instead of using

`{{ url('?param1=test&param2=test2&param3=kiswahili') }}`

Comment: This answer was already given, but with an explanation of _why_.

Answer (score -1):

in stead of blade `{{ $input }}` just used `<?php echo $input ?>` and link renders with out changing `&` in to `&amp;` . So this is just problem of blade.php , i don't know why it is like that, but i finally managed to solve my problem.

So this is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#table').DataTable({
                searching: false,
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: "<?php echo '/data?' .  $input ?>",
                columns: [
                    { data: 'date', name: 'date'},
                    { data: 'bid', name: 'bid' },
                    { data: 'auction_name', name: 'auction_name' },
                    { data: 'pics_urls', name: 'pics_urls' },
                    { data: 'company', name: 'company' },
                    { data: 'model_name_en', name: 'model_name_en' },
                    { data: 'model_type_en', name: 'model_type_en' },
                    { data: 'grade_en', name: 'grade_en' },
                    { data: 'mileage_en', name: 'mileage_en' },
                    { data: 'model_year_en', name: 'model_year_en' },
                    { data: 'color_en', name: 'color_en' },
                    { data: 'displacement', name: 'displacement' },
                    { data: 'transmission_en', name: 'transmission_en' },
                    { data: 'scores_en', name: 'scores_en' },
                    { data: 'start_price_en', name: 'start_price_en' },
                    { data: 'result_en', name: 'result_en' }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And my controller:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $input   = $request->getQueryString();

        return view('lots.browse')->withInput($input);
    }
```

And the result :

[image]

Comment: For this to be a useful answer, it needs to be rewritten. Please provide the example of your code to show what you changed.

Comment: It looks like your solution is to not properly encode the string, which will cause failure if certain characters are in the string being output.

Comment: @Michelangelo for some reason when i use blade template `{{ $input  }}` it always turn `&` in to `&amp;` but when i use plain php it renders link properly with out any encoding.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty thank you for your answer. I try many way to decode it. But the thing is any result that i have, blade will auto conver & in to `&amp;`